# Applications in Azure how connect to Microsoft Exchange on-premise

Tags: azure, exchange, exchange-2019

We are moving an application to Azure from on-premise which uses on-premise exchange 2019. The application will be moved as it is life and shift. Once the application is moved to Azure can you guide how the application will be authonicating back for exchange activity, We will have a local domain controller in Azure on VM

Any changes needed in Exchange on-premise side?
Any changes needed in the application?

Comment: You use what to gather the information? EWS is easilly routable to the world, MAPI not much.

Comment: What is the application used for? Send message via Exchange server?

You said “ We will have a local domain controller in Azure on VM”, did you mean it will be a new AD site in Azure VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications usually use pot 25 to send emails. In general, you should be able configure external IP address for outgoing traffic for which you can define a specific receive connector on Exchange scoped to that IP. Another option is to define some vm to send outbound emails for you.